# Why does MongoDB advise on upgrading MongoDB incrementally, version-by-version?

Tags: mongodb

Apologies if this question is too open-ended.

I have inherited an aging tech stack and am required to upgrade our 200GB MongoDB Community Edition v3.4 installation (hosted on Ubuntu 20) to MongoDB v5 in order to support some new features.

MongoDB advises that to install v5.0, one must be already on MongoDB v4.4:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/5.0-upgrade-standalone/

They say that if you are on a version older than 4.4, then you need to incrementally upgrade to v4.4 before upgrading to v5.

However, if you follow the links in that official upgrade tutorial, you will find that in order to upgrade to any version of MongoDB, they insist on you upgrading version-by-version, successively.

So for me on v3.4 the upgrade path will look like this:

```
v3.4 -> v3.6 -> v4.0 -> v4.2 -> v4.4 -> v5.0.13
```

Following these tutorials:

1. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-standalone/
2. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/4.0-upgrade-standalone/
3. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/4.2-upgrade-standalone/
4. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/4.4-upgrade-standalone/
5. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/5.0-upgrade-standalone/

I'm not entirely sure why this is necessary, as the tutorials themselves seem to mostly involve copying over newer binaries and then setting a feature compatibility version in the database config.

To test whether this was necessary I did a `mongodump` of our entire v3.4 database and then installed a standalone MongoDB v5.0.13 on the same server and then `mongorestore` to the new v5.0.13 database. Everything seems to work fine, `mongorestore` spent two hours recreating all the indexes as its last step (something various articles told me would not happen using the mongodump/mongorestore method).

I am able to connect Mongo clients to this new v5.0.13 Community instance without issue. All the data is there and I am able to query it just fine.

So my question is, why does MongoDB strongly advise doing the upgrade incrementally, one version at a time when dumping the database and restoring it to a new version of MongoDB seems to work just fine?

The only issues I have currently is having to rewrite some client code which is using an older Mongo Java driver. This is something I am going to have to do regardless of the upgrade method I used.

Our MongoDB instance is Community Edition and is a single, standalone instance (not a replica set) so I don't know if this matters. Perhaps the upgrade process described by MongoDB is for Mongo Cloud or for Enterprise?

I'm just looking for clarification on whether the simpler method I tried is going to cause me issues. Maybe I've missed something I hadn't considered.

Comment: Running a `mongodump` and then `mongorestore` into a **new** MongoDB is not an upgrade. When you do the upgrade according the documentation, then you have almost no downtime. If you can afford to have your MongoDB not available for couple of hours and if you have sufficient disk space, then you can `mongorestore` directly into a MongoDB 5.0 (or even 6.0?) database without any problems. If you require downtime as short a possible, then you need to upgrade  version-by-version.

Comment: Thanks for responding.

Okay, that makes sense. The 'upgrade' process described in these articles then is intended to minimise downtime as much as possible?

I can afford downtime on this database as the client applications that depend on it have been left to stagnate somewhat and nobody will miss them being down for a couple of days.

As for MongoDB v5 versus v6, we have to target v5 for now as our client applications are based on Grails 5 which ship with a Mongo Java driver version that supports MongoDB v5 at the latest.